# heightForRowAtIndexPath does not recognize the orientation

Tags: ios, uitableview, orientation

I have a tableView where I have to define a height of cells different depending if the device is in portrait or landscape, but it seems that this method does not recognize the device orientation. This method doesn't work:

```
  -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


  UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];//here doesn't recognize the orientation


 if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
     if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
         self.tableView.rowHeight =33.33333;

     }
     else if (deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || deviceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){

         self.tableView.rowHeight = 16.333333;
     }
 }

 else {
     if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
         self.tableView.rowHeight = 66.66666;

     }else if (deviceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || deviceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
         self.tableView.rowHeight = 33.333333;

     }

 }
 return self.tableView.rowHeight;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

to recognize statusBar oriantation, instead:

```
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton class methods
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation];